# React select remove selected option on search

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-select-search

is there a way to always show the selected option on the menu even after searching for some thing else

here is the code I used

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select/async";
const CheckboxDropdown = ({
  options,
  defaultValue,
  loadOptions,
  handleCheckboxSelect,
}) => {
  const selectDefaultValue = defaultValue;
  
  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <Select
        defaultMenuIsOpen
        defaultOptions={options}
        cacheOptions
        loadOptions={loadOptions}
        options={options}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        isMulti
        onChange={handleCheckboxSelect}
        noOptionsMessage={() => "No options available"}
        className="w-full"
        isClearable={false}
        placeholder="Type site name..."
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default CheckboxDropdown;
```

Comment: Which plug-in you used ?

Comment: I used react select

Comment: add sample in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: You need to pass stored value in  `value={selectedOption}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`react-select` has a prop called [filterOption](https://react-select.com/advanced#custom-filter-logic) where you can pass custom filter logic.

Check [this CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-dawn-e2wgg?file=/src/App.js) to see my implementation.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Select from "react-select";

const options = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" },
  { value: "Apple", label: "apple" },
  { value: "Orange", label: "orange" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState([]); //add initial state

  const handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    setSelectedOption(selectedOption);
  };

  const filterOptions = (candidate, input) => {
    if (input) {
      if (candidate.label.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase()))
        return true;
      if (
        selectedOption.some((opt) => {
          if (opt.value === candidate.value) return true;
          else return false;
        })
      )
        return true;
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select
        defaultValue={{ value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" }} // default value must be like this.
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={handleChange}
        options={options}
        isMulti
        hideSelectedOptions={false}
        isSearchable
        filterOption={filterOptions}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you it worked the only problem with you code was you need to add [] as initial state

Comment: but it has rerender problem it rerender 15 on focus

Answer (score 2):

Try this code it's work

```
const App = () => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState();

  const handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    setSelectedOption(selectedOption);
  }
  const options = [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        isMulti
        hideSelectedOptions={false}
        defaultValue={{ value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' }} // default value must be like this.
        value={selectedOption} //You forgot pass this  parameter
        onChange={handleChange}
        options={options}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: it still don't work. the thing that I want according to your example is that first it should has properly isMulti and hideSelectedOptions={false}
then for example I select chocolate and search for strawberry  I want chocolate to be shown on the menu list as well since I selected it before

Comment: I update my answer pls check

Comment: sorry it didn't work the filterOption was required